# How to make Hapi auto reload app during developing

Tags: node.js, hapi.js

I'm new to *Hapi *framework. During development, I have to restart the hapi server whenever I made any changes to the code.

For the view part, I can add an option `{isCached: false}`to make the view read the latest html file every time. *However, is there an easy setting to make it reload code automatically whenever it is changed?*

**UPDATE:**

Thanks to *dylants*' suggestion, Nodemon works great.

However, in my app there is a selenium-standalone child process, whenever the `nodemon` restarts, it will generate an error log. `...Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again...`

I have tried https://github.com/remy/nodemon#controlling-shutdown-of-your-script, it doesn't help.

Comment: Not really Hapi specific, but have you looked into [nodemon](http://nodemon.io/)?

Comment: Thank you so much. It works! However, in my app there is a selenium-standalone child process, whenever the nodemon restarts, it will generate an error log. "...Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again..." I have tried https://github.com/remy/nodemon#controlling-shutdown-of-your-script this, it doesn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

I've used [nodemon](https://github.com/remy/nodemon). You just start your server with `$ nodemon` instead of `$ npm start` and every time you make a change to your server code it restarts the server.

Answer (score 4):

I have found [node-dev](https://github.com/fgnass/node-dev) to work well for me.

```
npm install -g node-dev
```

Answer (score 3):

I personally prefer pm2 to achieve this.

`pm2 start app --watch`

More info about pm2: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/

Comment: I have tried it : installation is easy and the result is satisfying. However, we have to take care of which edition of pm2 that we want. pm 2 runtime is the free edition, whereas pm2 plus and pm2 enterprise are not free. As for Strongloop (http://strong-pm.io), my installation failed or was not complete, so I couldn't use it.